# How to determine what's causing JIT status to shows as "Disabled" in phpinfo()

Tags: php, jit, php-8, cloudways

I've set-up everything as best as I can and yet I see JIT status as **Disabled**.

Here's what I have:

```
echo (function_exists('opcache_get_status') 
      && opcache_get_status()['jit']['enabled']) ? 'JIT enabled' : 'JIT disabled';
```

Returns:

```
JIT disabled
```

Then I have this:

```
print_r([
            'opcache.jit' =>  ini_get("opcache.jit"),
            'opcache.enable' => ini_get('opcache.enable'),
            'opcache.enable_cli' => ini_get('opcache.enable_cli'),
            'opcache.jit_buffer_size' => ini_get('opcache.jit_buffer_size') 
    ]);
```

Returns:

```
Array
(
    [opcache.jit] => tracing
    [opcache.enable] => 1
    [opcache.enable_cli] => 1
    [opcache.jit_buffer_size] => 300M
)
```

And finally, this code:

```
opcache_get_status()['jit']
```

Returns:

```
array(7) {
  ["enabled"] => bool(false)
  ["on"] => bool(false)
  ["kind"] => int(5)
  ["opt_level"] => int(4)
  ["opt_flags"] => int(6)
  ["buffer_size"] => int(0)
  ["buffer_free"] => int(0)
}
```

What can I do, or where do I look to figure out why JIT status is *false*?

Edit: JIT is enabled via these lines in Cloudways panel, if that helps:

```
php_admin_value[opcache.enable]=1
php_admin_value[opcache.enable_cli]=1
php_admin_value[opcache.jit_buffer_size]=300M
```

Comment: ckhatton, the only solution I know to this is in my answer below -- which is to ask Cloudways support to add a config file.

Comment: Thank you. I eventually found out it was because I had xDebug enabled, which prevents JIT from starting

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem. In file  /etc/php/8.1/mods-available/opcache.ini saw duplicated parametr opcache.jit=off. Replace it to opcache.jit=1255 and JIT will rinning

Answer (score 0):

With Cloudways, at present one needs to create a ticket with their support, and:

1. Explain to them how JIT is not working, give screenshot of the `print_r` output.
2. Ask them to create a file:

   `/etc/php/8.x/mods-available/30-jit.ini`

*Change 8.x to your version of PHP.*

3. Request them to paste the following contents in above file:

   `opcache.enable=1`

   `opcache.jit_buffer_size=128M`

   `opcache.jit=1255`

*Adjust the values as needed*

4. Lastly ask them to enable the file by creating a soft link:

   `ln -s /etc/php/8.x/mods-available/30-jit.ini /etc/php/8.x/fpm/conf.d/30-jit.ini`

Until they fix their hosting dashboard, this is the only way I am able to get JIT working with Cloudways.